# I am unable to open raster using rasterio

Tags: python, error, rasterio, visualisation

I am trying to open a raster file that I have downloaded using rasterio. It is a satellite image raster file of part of UBC in my data folder which I downloaded from [Abacus Data Network.](https://abacus.library.ubc.ca/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:11272.1/AB2/6PFOWL) the However, I get a feedback that access was denied. Here is my code and the error message.

```
import rasterio

dataset = rasterio.open("\\Users\\PERSONAL\\Desktop\\GIS\\Canada_Data\\481E_5456N")
```

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File rasterio\_base.pyx:310, in rasterio._base.DatasetBase.__init__()
File rasterio\_base.pyx:221, in rasterio._base.open_dataset()
File rasterio\_err.pyx:221, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_pointer()
CPLE_OpenFailedError: \Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\GIS\Canada_Data\481E_5456N: Permission denied
```

This was the final error message:

```
RasterioIOError: \Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\GIS\Canada_Data\481E_5456N: Permission denied
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should check permission on this file for your user (chmod , chown ... etc)

Comment: These commands are for Unix. I am operating on Windows 10.

Comment: I have added the link to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce. I downloaded the data from [481E_5456N.zip](https://abacus.library.ubc.ca/file.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:11272.1/AB2/6PFOWL/HRRR0A&version=2.0), extracted it and ran your code with the path adjusted accordingly.

```
dataset = rasterio.open("481E_5456N/481E_5456N.tif")
print(dataset.meta)
```

Output:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint8', 'nodata': None, 'width': 10000, 'height': 10000, 'count': 4, 'crs': None, 'transform': Affine(0.1, 0.0, 481000.0, 0.0, -0.1, 5457000.0)}
```

I note you don't have a .tif extension on your path. You may have tried to open the folder not the geotiff.

You may also need to check your path.  If you are trying to use a UNC path like `\\server\share\folder`then you either need to use:

- a double double backslash at the start `"\\\\server\\share\\folder\\file.tif"`,
- or use a raw string `r"\\server\share\folder\file.tif"`